How to prevent third party libraries from configuring logging
I'm writing an application in which I'm configuring logging in this way:
import logging.config

loglevel = "INFO"

logging.config.dictConfig({
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "formatters": {
        "my_formatter": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s",
        },
    },
    "handlers": {
        "my_handler": {
            "level": loglevel,
            "formatter": "my_formatter",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "stream": "ext://sys.stdout",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "my_app": {
            "level": loglevel,
        },
        # emits too much on DEBUG and INFO, so it should be WARNING at least
        "noisy_third_party_logger": {
            "level": max(logging.WARNING, logging._nameToLevel[loglevel]),
        },
    },
    "root": {  # catch all propagated records and handle them
        "handlers": ["my_handler"],
    },
})

While third party libraries should never configure logging on their own, some, for various reasons that may or may not be reasonable, still do.
My biggest pain point is if they attach their own handlers, so I searched the logging module for a way to "freeze" the current logging configuration except for adding propagating loggers.
Unfortunately, there is no way to do that. And from looking at the code, I'm not brave enough to monkey-patch something in myself.

To sum things up:

I want third party libraries to emit logs, even if I didn't explicitly list their loggers in my "loggers"-dictionary

as a consequence, I don't want to set "disable_existing_loggers" to True


I don't want third party libraries to attach their own handlers to any logger
I'd like to enforce that all loggers propagate, but am not sure if that's actually a good idea

Is there a safe way to do this, or a logging-wrapper that I can install which does this already?

If the most painful thing is that they add handlers, you could patch Logger.addHandler to be no-op when it's being called by those libraries (via traceback's utilities) (or when self.name is something well-known).

that would probably work, I don't think I've ever seen someone write their own logger class. what do you mean by traceback's utilities for patching?

You could use traceback to see who is calling your patched addHandler and no-op it.

A somewhat silly example, but as discussed, you could patch setLevel (or addHandler, but this was simpler to demonstrate), to cancel out what the evil third-party library wants to do to your precious configuration.
import logging
import traceback


def third_party_library():
    # Mwahaha! I am an evil third-party library, and I declare
    # that I will need all `requinks` to be at DEBUG level!
    logger = logging.getLogger("requinks")
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.debug("OH YES! THE VERBOSITY!")
    logger.warning("This might hurt...")


def patch_set_level():
    original_set_level = logging.Logger.setLevel

    def patched_set_level(self, level):
        for frame in traceback.extract_stack():
            if frame.name == "third_party_library":  # This is the evil library!
                # In reality, you'd probably look at `frame.filename` instead.
                print("Nixing level change from evil library!")
                return
        original_set_level(self, level)

    logging.Logger.setLevel = patched_set_level


def configure_logging():
    patch_set_level()  # (This could be done _after_ we finish setting up things too.)
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)  # We need debug logging for most things.
    logging.getLogger("requinks").setLevel(logging.INFO)  # Requinks is usually too verbose, though, so shush...


def main():
    configure_logging()
    third_party_library()
    logging.debug("Hello! We're up and running!")


main()

This logs out
Nixing level change from evil library!
WARNING:requinks:This might hurt...
DEBUG:root:Hello! We're up and running!

so as you can see, the very very unnecessarily verbose requinks (nothing to do with requests, oh no) log from the third-party library just doesn't happen.

thanks, it took me a bit to get it to work in a way that I like, but the tip with using traceback as a way to exert access control was real neat. I'll post another answer with what exactly I ended up doing, since it ended up being a fair bit different (too different for me to edit it into this post, at least).

Expanding on @AKX's answer, I adapted it to my use case of "forbid anyone but me from configuring log-handlers" as opposed to "forbid this one library from configuring log-handlers". Voilà:
import logging.config
import traceback
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Literal, Any, Callable

# This code is intended to be part of a distributable library, so
# MODULE_PATH will be something like "my_lib.utils", and not "__main__".
# The way "access control" works here, it's not easy to safely port it
# into something that is run as a script.
MODULE_PATH = __name__
PACKAGE_NAME = MODULE_PATH.split(".")[0]
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
LogLevel = Literal["DEBUG", "INFO", "WARNING", "ERROR"]


def add_handler(self: logging.Logger, hdlr: logging.Handler, original: Callable):
    """Patched version of `logging.Logger.addHandler` with access control.

    If the original `addHandler` method is patched with this function, only calls that
    originated from within `MODULE_PATH.setup_logging` may add handlers to a logger.
    """
    for frame in traceback.extract_stack():
        try:
            path = Path(frame.filename)
            components = [path.stem, *path.parts[-2::-1]]
            frame_module = ".".join(components[components.index(PACKAGE_NAME):: -1])
        except ValueError:
            continue  # PACKAGE_NAME not found, try next frame
        if frame.name == setup_logging.__name__ and frame_module == MODULE_PATH:
            return original(self, hdlr)

    log.warning(
        f"Logger '{self.name}' tried to attach a handler '{hdlr}'; "
        f"skipping that and propagating instead."
    )
    self.propagate = True


def setup_logging(loglevel: LogLevel, *, tyrant: bool):
    """Set up basic logging to stdout.

    Args:
        loglevel: The log level that is used for all handlers and loggers.
        tyrant: If set, detach existing logging handlers and shut off loggers from
            attaching handlers through means that don't involve calling this function.
            This behavior is in line with the pattern of "all loggers propagate and only
            the root has handlers" that we're going for.
    """
    # basic logger configuration, hard-coded for generic use-cases
    config: dict[str, Any] = {
        "version": 1,
        "disable_existing_loggers": False,
        "formatters": {
            "my_formatter": {
                "format": "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s",
            },
        },
        "handlers": {
            "my_handler": {
                "level": loglevel,
                "formatter": "my_formatter",
                "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
                "stream": "ext://sys.stdout",
            },
        },
        "loggers": {
            # this library is very noisy on DEBUG
            "noisy_third_party_logger": {
                "level": max(logging.INFO, getattr(logging, loglevel)),
            },
        },
        "root": {  # catch all propagated records and handle them
            "handlers": ["my_handler"],
            "level": loglevel,
        },
    }
    # if we want to be in control of log-emission, we detach any existing handlers
    # and forbid outside callers from attaching new ones
    logs: list[tuple[LogLevel, str]] = []
    if tyrant:
        for name, logger in logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict.items():
            if (
                isinstance(logger, logging.Logger)
                and logger.handlers
                and logger.name not in config["loggers"]
            ):
                for handler in logger.handlers:
                    logger.removeHandler(handler)
                logs.append(("WARNING", f"Removed handlers from logger '{name}'."))
                if not logger.propagate:
                    logger.propagate = True
                    logs.append(
                        ("WARNING", f"Enforced propagation for logger '{name}'.")
                    )

        # need to assign the old handler a name here to avoid infinite recursion due to
        # delayed evaluation within the lambda
        original = logging.Logger.addHandler
        logging.Logger.addHandler = lambda self, hdlr: add_handler(self, hdlr, original)

    # do the actual configuration, and inform the caller about how things went down
    logging.config.dictConfig(config)
    for lvl, msg in logs:
        log.log(getattr(logging, lvl), msg)
    log.info(f"Logger configuration set up successfully.")

It's also part of the comments, but to re-iterate; this snippet can't be copied into a script, it expects to be part of a module that is imported from a library.
And this here is the rather complicated test-suite, because pytest doesn't handle it well if the code-under-test switches out the root-logger:
import logging.config

import pytest

from my_lib.utils import setup_logging


def retain_pytest_handlers(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        pytest_handlers = [
            handler
            for handler in logging.getLogger().handlers
            if handler.__module__ == "_pytest.logging"
        ]
        ret = f(*args, **kwargs)
        for handler in pytest_handlers:
            if handler not in logging.getLogger().handlers:
                logging.getLogger().addHandler(handler)
        return ret

    return wrapper


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def keep_pytest_handlers_during_dict_conf(monkeypatch):  # noqa: PT004
    monkeypatch.setattr(
        logging.config, "dictConfig", retain_pytest_handlers(logging.config.dictConfig)
    )


def test_setup_logging_tyrant_behavior_pre_setup(monkeypatch, caplog):
    # this is a no-op, but since tyrant=True patches that function as well, this call is
    # the easiest way to roll that patch back
    monkeypatch.setattr(logging.Logger, "addHandler", logging.Logger.addHandler)

    foo_logger = logging.getLogger("foo")
    foo_logger.propagate = False
    foo_logger.level = logging.NOTSET
    foo_logger.addHandler(logging.Handler())

    setup_logging("DEBUG", tyrant=True)

    # act
    foo_logger.info("foo")

    # assert
    assert "Removed handlers from logger 'foo'." in caplog.text
    assert "Enforced propagation for logger 'foo'." in caplog.text
    assert caplog.records[-1].message == "foo"


def test_setup_logging_tyrant_behavior_post_setup(monkeypatch, caplog):
    # this is a no-op, but since tyrant=True patches that function as well, this call is
    # the easiest way to roll that patch back
    monkeypatch.setattr(logging.Logger, "addHandler", logging.Logger.addHandler)

    setup_logging("DEBUG", tyrant=True)

    foo_logger = logging.getLogger("foo")
    foo_logger.propagate = False
    foo_logger.level = logging.NOTSET
    foo_logger.addHandler(logging.Handler())

    # act
    foo_logger.info("foo")

    # assert
    assert "Logger 'foo' tried to attach a handler" in caplog.text
    assert "skipping that and propagating instead." in caplog.text
    assert caplog.records[-1].message == "foo"

Enjoy, may the logging-engine not bite you as hard as it bit me.
